# Deleting array elements when a button is clicked without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, local-storage

I am creating a delete function for an offline web app without using jQuery.

A delete button is created when a "task" is added. Originally it was for a check box but I think it looks better with a button. When a "task" is added, 7 arrays are created. One for the "subject", "type", "date", "instructor", "title", "description", and the delete button.

```
for(var c = 0; c<colCount; c++ ){
        var addCell = row.insertCell(c);
        switch(c){
            case 0:
                addCell.innerHTML = subjectClass;
                break;
            case 1:
                addCell.innerHTML = roomClass;
                break;
            case 2:
                addCell.innerHTML = instructorClass;
                break;
            case 3:
                addCell.innerHTML = dayClass;
                break;
            case 4:
                addCell.innerHTML = startTimeClass;
                break;
            case 5:
                addCell.innerHTML = endTimeClass;
                break;
            case 6:
                addCell.innerHTML = addCell.innerHTML + "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow('taskTable')'/>";
                break;
```

And this is the code I had for the checkbox...
I tried doing this but it does not seem to work.

```
function deleteRow(taskTable){
var table = document.getElementById("taskTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var subjectR = localStorage.getItem("subjectInfo");
var typeR = localStorage.getItem("typeInfo");
var dueDateR = localStorage.getItem("dueDateInfo");
var instructorR = localStorage.getItem("instructorInfo");
var titleR =localStorage.getItem("titleInfo");
var descriptionR =localStorage.getItem("descriptionInfo");

var subjectAll = JSON.parse(subjectR);
var typeAll = JSON.parse(typeR);
var dueDateAll = JSON.parse(dueDateR);
var instructorAll = JSON.parse(instructorR);
var titleAll = JSON.parse(titleR);
var descriptionAll = JSON.parse(descriptionR);

for(var c=1; c<rowCount; c++){
    var row = table.rows[c];

        var arrayLength = subjectAll.length;
        table.deleteRow(c);
        var removeValue = arrayLength-c;
        subjectAll.splice(removeValue,1);
        typeAll.splice(removeValue,1);
        dueDateAll.splice(removeValue,1);
        instructorAll.splice(removeValue,1);
        titleAll.splice(removeValue,1);
        descriptionAll.splice(removeValue,1);

        localStorage.setItem("subjectInfo", JSON.stringify(subjectAll));
        localStorage.setItem("typeInfo", JSON.stringify(typeAll));
        localStorage.setItem("dueDateInfo", JSON.stringify(dueDateAll));
        localStorage.setItem("instructorInfo", JSON.stringify(instructorAll));
        localStorage.setItem("titleInfo", JSON.stringify(titleAll));
        localStorage.setItem("descriptionInfo", JSON.stringify(descriptionAll));
}
```

}

Comment: How did you manage to create a database upside down. Traditionally you would store a full row in a line in an array rather than an array of column values. Is there a way you can change the structure.

Comment: To be honest, I have the same thing in mind but I can't change the structure because "I can work around it".